# Google Apps Script - consolidate executions from "on edit" or "on change" triggers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am developing a simple script for an inventory tracking spreadsheet that sends an email alert listing low stock items with current quantities. Everything seems to be working well...except, it works TOO well.

I'm depending on Google's native "On Edit" trigger to initiate the script. Unfortunately that means that when I update the inventory on 10 items (which I often do), the script runs 10 times and sends 10 email notifications.

In an effort to consolidate the 10 emails into one, I used Utilities.sleep(300000) to insert a delay before the script runs, hoping that it would then only run once and produce one email with all the edits made during those five minutes.

As I'm sure any expert would already know, I ended up with the same 10 emails, just delayed by 5 minutes. It seems Google runs the script in parallel with respect to the number of triggers.

**How can I turn my spamming script into a consolidated email notification that is only sent once, when all edits have been made?**

This is my first coding project. I am a coding novice and know only what I have learned through StackOverflow and Google. This question may have been answered somewhere and I just don't know what to search to find it. Thanks in advance for any help/guidance!

Comment: Hi, What I would do is convert the onEdit trigger to mark the row as modified in a new column at the end of the row. Then add a time based trigger to look for all the modified rows, sum them into an email and update the status to non-modified.  Hop this helps.

Comment: Or don't use a trigger at all to send the emails.  Just run the function from a menu.

Comment: One of the probems with overusing onedits is that they all must complete in 30 seconds.

Comment: I chose the onEdit trigger because the spreadsheet is not updated regularly, but I want to know immediately when it does get updated. An onEdit trigger seems to be the only one that fits the docket. A menu function may work, but I'm relying on employees to remember to actually click that button (it's hard enough to get them to remember to fill out the spreadsheet)...

Answer (score 0):

first, look at [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail), I think your best bet would be to use some form of `update(recipient, subject, body)` to set up the emails to update the same one email constantly then put the "On Edit" below it to start the timer that would send the email so it would constantly update, but only send after an edit and a delay

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

An `onEdit` fires every single time the script is edited. If you don't want to send an email every time there's an edit, I don't think it's a good option to use an `onEdit` trigger.

#### Workaround #1. Use a button or a custom menu:

I'd suggest you to fire this function via a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) or a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms) instead, so that you actively decide when to send an email.

#### Workaround #2. Time-driven trigger:

If you don't want to manually fire the script, another option would be to install a time-based trigger instead (see the available triggers [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#top_of_page)), which would fire periodically (could be hourly, daily, every X minutes, etc.), and would check whether there has been any change to the low stock items since last execution, and send an email if that's the case.

In order to check whether there has been any change, I'd consider using [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to store these low stock items every time an email is sent, and compare those properties to current data every time the function is executed.

In broad terms, the script called by the time-driven trigger should do this:

```
function sendEmailIfChanges() {
  // Get low items from spreadsheet
  // Retrieve stored properties from previous execution
  // Compare current low stock items with current execution
  // If there is change between both lists of items (item IDs, or stock quantities)
  // send an email and store current low stock items via PropertiesService
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Custom Menus in Google Workspace](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)
- [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

Comment: Workaround #2 sounds like it's going to work well for me. I'll give it a shot, come back and report. Thanks!

Comment: @Talon You're welcome! If you need more details on the code to be used, let me know. I'd consider updating my answer to provide a working code snippet.